# Serializing checkboxes inside table (datatables)

Tags: jquery, serialization, checkbox, datatables

I'm using jquery datatables, the created table html is:

```
<table id="product-table">
  <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td>
      <div class="vd_checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group" id="c3800">
        <label for="c3800"></label>
      </div>
    </td> ...
</table>
```

I'm using this code to serialize checkboxes to be sent via ajax to be processed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var table;
$(document).ready(function () {
table = $('#product-table').DataTable(options);
$('#b_submit').click(function () {
var data = table.$('input').serialize();
alert("The following data would have been submitted to the server: \n\n" +
                    data.substr(0, 120) + '...');
return false;
});
</script>
```

But this doesn't serialize any checkbox (alerts the message only). How can I serialize them?

Comment: Try substituting `table.find('input').serialize()` for `table.$('input').serialize();` ? , though `input` elements not appear to have `name` , `value` attributes ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: What data would be serialized ? `type=checkbox` appear not able to be serialized ?

Comment: tried to change input type to text, not working.

Comment: `input` element requires `type=text` , `name=name_here` , `value=value_here` attributes to be serialized to `name_here=value_here` ; also not appear to be a `#b_submit` element at `html` ? Can create stacksnippets , http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Great thanks @guest271314. Worked. Thanks again +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `type=text` , `name=name_here` , `value=value_here` attributes to be serialized to `name_here=value_here` ; also not appear to be a `#b_submit` element at `html` ?